# Redirect SFTP command log in Shell Script to a File

Tags: unix, sftp

I have this code on my shell script

```
sftp myuser@192.168.0.15 <<EOF
cd /c/folder
lcd /ux/source
put -p *.csv
exit
EOF
```

It works ok and shows the logs in the console. How can I redirect the logs to a file instead on the console?

I know this can work when I redirect

```
sh myscript.sh >> mylogfile.log
```

What if the filename of the logfile is defined in the script itself? How do I redirect the sftp command in my script to a file?

Comment: What does it mean *"defined in the script itself"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

`sftp myuser@192.168.0.15 <<EOF`

to this

`sftp myuser@192.168.0.15 <<EOF >> logfile`

Comment: it is not allowing me to do if I do the following

sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -oPort=${port} -oIdentityFile=${keyFile} ${username}@${host} <<EOF
        cd ${occ}
        pwd
        quit
EOF>>mytest.log


and I get a warning

./test.sh: line 21: warning: here-document at line 16 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')